# Is a memory leak created by a series of [array addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:someVariable]?];

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, nsnumber, alloc

Do I create multiple memory leaks by:

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:boolVariable1]];
[array addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:boolVariable2]];
[array addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:intVariable]];
[array addObject:[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:floatVariable]];
[array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
[array release];
```

Is it better to use:

```
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intVariable]];
```

Comment: If "better" means "not incorrect", then yes :-)

Answer (score 5):

The [rule](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) is simple: every time you call `alloc`/`new`/`copy*`/`retain`, you must balance it with a call to `auto-`/`release`, else you've a memory leak. In the code sample, you send `alloc` to `NSNumber` four times, but have no corresponding releases, so the four `NSNumber`s will leak.

`numberWithInt:` isn't `new`, `alloc`, `retain` and doesn't start with `copy`, so it doesn't need to be balanced with a call to `auto-`/`release`.

There are also a few different tools you can use to [find memory leaks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html), such as [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 2):

The call to

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:intVariable]
```

is conceptually equivalent to

```
[[[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:intVariable] autorelease]
```

so yes, in the example you gave, it would be simpler to use `-numberWithInt:`.

```
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:boolVariable1]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithWithBool:boolVariable2]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:intVariable]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:floatVariable]];
[array writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
[array release];
```

Otherwise, you'd need to add a call to `-autorelease` on each argument passed to the array.